# Detect when user interact with IFrame JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I found a lot of posts about that but I still didn't find solution.

I am trying to detect when user in doing something on IFrame. Example, mousemove or keypress. My IFrame is different domain than website which display that IFrame.

How I can detect mouse move or keypress on IFrame which is different domain?

Thanks

Comment: If that were possible, what would prevent a malicious website to display, for example, the yahoo login page in the iframe and read all keypresses inside the password field?

Comment: Yes I understand what you talking about.

Comment: But is it possible to make some configuration on another website which can allow CORS? Because I own child domain website.

Comment: If you own both domains then use CORS or post message methods described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook up events to the IFrame like any other element - for example `$('#my_iframe').mouseover(function(){ alert('over!'); });` **will** fire whenever the user mouse over the iframe.

But that's not useful, really. If you want to capture events which are happening on the *content* of the frame, you can't do this. e.g. `$('#my_frame').contents().mouseover(function(){ alert('moved!'); });` will not work.

This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), and there's no way around it!

Comment: Thanks for your post. So you mean that if is different domain I cannot send JS event from child to parent window?

Comment: Well, if you have control over the page the frame is pointing at, you can add the listener on _that_ page, which will fire. If you have no control over the page which is loaded in the frame, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using "on"..ala..

CAVEAT: this will note changes in the IFRAME container sitting on the page. Since, the parent page will have knowledge of this. This will not catch events emitting from a seperate iframe or the page therein, not controlled by parent.

```
$("iframe").on("mouseover focus",function(){ 
     // do your stuff
});
```

If you want to only act on an iframe with a certain source, then something like:

```
var usedSrc = /facebook|twitter/;

    $('iframe').on('mouseover focus', 
      function () {
          if(usedSrc.test($(this).attr('src'))){
                 // do your stuff
          }
      }  
    );​
```

Comment: note: this is listening for events on the iframe container, it will not catch events originating within the actual iframe, as the op requests.

Comment: Thanks for this post. But I already try with mouseover and it doesn't work for me because it only work when user move mouse from parent page to IFrame. If is user focused only in IFrame and moving mouse only in IFrame this event doesn't happened.

Comment: have you tried adding "focus" to the event handler? I updated my original code. But yes, if iframe html page sets the event, then yeah - not sure what can be done.

Comment: Yes I tried. But unfortunately doesn't work like I need. General idea is if user doesn't work nothing I need after some time do something e.g. detect when user doesn't work nothing 5 min.  If user leave mouse on iframe, iframe will be focused but I still don't know whether user doing something or he doing nothing. Because I need information when user moving mouse or typing.